# Compare average execution time for two queries

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to compare average execution time for two queries?

The main objective is to know which one is faster in one particular context.

I know I can run it twice or more then compare (but it's not sufficient), or run explain (because it's better to understand, but I just want to observe).

So, my question is: **can I measure it by just comparing an average execution time?** Just like in benchmarks about anything: it runs something a lot of time, then returns an average. I know it depends on the machine and the version of postgreSQL. I don't want to use a programming language to do that, because maybe it might distort the result.

*It could be considered to broad; do not downvote too fast, I can edit if you need more information!*

Comment: You can execute dynamic SQL in a loop in PL/pgSQL, measure the time and calculate an average.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Ok thank you! Could you please elaborate and write it as an answer?

Comment: Use @eurotrash's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I frequently use something like this to check something's performance:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    start   TIMESTAMP;
    end     TIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
    start := clock_timestamp();
    FOR i IN 1..100000 LOOP
        PERFORM --...
    END LOOP;
    end := clock_timestamp();
    RAISE NOTICE '%', end - start;
END $$
```

Though you need to beware of optimisations PG might make - for example, caching the result of a stable or immutable function - and guard against it to make sure your test is doing what you expect.